# SQL query group and filter by field value

Tags: sql, postgresql

for example have this table:

```
ID   ProdId   Status
1    111      None
2    111      Success
3    222      Process
4    222      Fail
5    333      Process
6    333      Process
7    444      None
```

I need to group by field `ProdId` and exclude all rows that contain `Status` - "Success" or "Fail"
So, result of this sql query must be:

```
6    333      Process
7    444      None
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried? And your expected result doesn’t match your sample data and requirements.

Comment: Do you need the ID column too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample data you posted, the below filtering with `NOT EXISTS` will work:

```
select max(t.id) id, t.prodid, max(t.process)
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where prodid = t.prodid and status in ('Success', 'Fail')
)
group by t.prodid
```

although it's unclear what you would need in case you have rows like:

```
5    333      Process
6    333      None
```

Edit:
After your comment, I think you need this join:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select max(t.id) id, t.prodid
  from tablename t
  where not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where prodid = t.prodid and status in ('Success', 'Fail')
  ) 
  group by t.prodid
) g on g.id = t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1YuD4jpMNGhRDxD6V7Px5/0).
Results:

```
| id  | prodid | status  |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 6   | 333    | Process |
| 7   | 444    | None    |
```

Comment: in that case any of these two rows. Have to get only rows which ProdId do not contain status SUCCESS and FAIL.

Comment: Hm, I  tried quickly it works...I need to try with more details. Do you use sqlalechemy?

Comment: Another question...I cannot find info about t.* statement what does it mean?

Comment: It means all the columns of the table t which is the alias of the table `tablename`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the `WITH`  clause as an aggregation pipeline and just then filter the results, so you wouldn't need to perform the aggegation again in a subquery or in the WHERE sentence.

```
WITH grouped AS 
(
    SELECT max(id) AS id, 
                prodid, array_agg(status) 
                AS statuses
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY prodid
    )
SELECT * FROM grouped
WHERE    
    NOT('Fail' = ANY(statuses))
AND 
    NOT('Success' = ANY(statuses))
```

(see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/okYf8wkyn7Aj8tKaGRWSft/0)

Now, you don't really say you need the maximum ID or its corresponding status. I'd find more useful to check out which  statuses does the product have or has had in its evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select id, prodid, status
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where status in ('Success', 'Fail') as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below query for mySql database. If you do not want the count column you can remove 'count(*)' from the query.

```
select * , count(*) from customers1 where status not in('success','fail') group by pordid;
```

Comment: No, this query contain data with SerialId which status "Sucess" and Fail -

Comment: which database you are using? I have generated the results using mysql.

Comment: The database used is given in the question but your query should be equally incorrect in any sql database